# FloatingActionButton invisible in case of music starts playing - SlideupPanelLayout

Tags: android

FloatingActionButton works well till the time, music is not playing in the app.I am using this [library](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel).

**Issue is coming in android 6.0 before it was working fine**

When i play the music by clicking on fab button, and starts moving the slide panel fab button goes invisible.

Issues-:

1- Slideup animation is not working well, dragging of slideup layout stops working.

2- Fab button goes invisible.

Important thing here is everything works well , till the time music is not playing.

For playing music i am using a background service.

Could there be any problem with the memory issue or something else?

Below is activity layout --

```
    <com.sothree.slidinguppanel.FloatingActionButtonLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    sothree:umanoFabMode="circular_reveal">
    <com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
        xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        sothree:umanoAnchorPoint="@+id/handle"
        sothree:umanoPanelHeight="58dp"
        sothree:umanoShadowHeight="4dp"
        sothree:umanoParallaxOffset="100dp"
        sothree:umanoDragView="@+id/trackdetails"
        sothree:umanoOverlay="true"
        sothree:umanoScrollableView="@+id/now_playlist">
        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/drawer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            tools:context="com.ultimo.musicplayer.activity.MainActivity">
        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <!--Main Content goes here-->
            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
            <!--Toolbar and tabs-->
            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:popupTheme="@style/PopupMenu"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    app:tabGravity="fill"
                    sothree:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
                    app:tabMode="scrollable"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
            <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>
        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
        <include layout="@layout/mediaplayer_layout"/>
    </com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_play"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:src="@drawable/play"
        android:clickable="true"/>
</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.FloatingActionButtonLayout>
```

Already posted question on library's issues list [here](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel/issues/730).

Comment: SlidingUpPanel Layout should have only two child view so you need to fix that.

Comment: It has two Childs only.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some problem in the Layout that you have created. I am also using the UmanoSlidingPanelLayout to create a MusicPlayer.

Try this.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start"
tools:context="com.ultimo.musicplayer.activity.MainActivity">

<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.FloatingActionButtonLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    sothree:umanoFabMode="circular_reveal">

    <com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        sothree:umanoAnchorPoint="@+id/handle"
        sothree:umanoDragView="@+id/trackdetails"
        sothree:umanoOverlay="true"
        sothree:umanoPanelHeight="58dp"
        sothree:umanoParallaxOffset="100dp"
        sothree:umanoScrollableView="@+id/now_playlist"
        sothree:umanoShadowHeight="4dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <!--Main Content goes here-->
            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
            <!--Toolbar and tabs-->
            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:popupTheme="@style/PopupMenu"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                    app:tabGravity="fill"
                    app:tabMode="scrollable"
                    sothree:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp" />
            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/mediaplayer_layout" />
    </com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_play"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/play" />
</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.FloatingActionButtonLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Was using this same layout before , had to change because of some issue in android 6.0 in rendering of layout.